# C# open other program in form panel

Tags: c#, process, exe, panel

Hello I am a beginner developer in Korea.

I'm making. Program. The program runs three exe (developed in c ++, c #) on one form and puts the program into the panel.

Now I put the program in C ++ or other languages into the panel. However, windows programs built with C # do not keep on the panel.
Here is part of my code:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr Handle, int x, int y, int w, int h, bool repaint);

    static readonly int GWL_STYLE = -16;
    static readonly int WS_VISIBLE = 0x10000000;


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            Process p = Process.Start("C:\\Users\\sonmi\\OneDrive\\Japan_Bunge_alpha\\Japan_Bunge_alpha\\bin\\Debug\\Japan_Bunge_alpha"); //C# program
            Process p2 = Process.Start("C:\\Users\\sonmi\\Desktop\\astana_test\\astana\\Server\\Server_CES"); //C++ program

            p.WaitForInputIdle();

            Thread.Sleep(100);
            SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, this.Handle);
            SetWindowLong(p.MainWindowHandle, GWL_STYLE, WS_VISIBLE);
            MoveWindow(p.MainWindowHandle, 0, 0, panel1.Width, panel1.Height, true);


            p2.WaitForInputIdle();
            SetParent(p2.MainWindowHandle, panel2.Handle);
            SetWindowLong(p2.MainWindowHandle, GWL_STYLE, WS_VISIBLE);
            MoveWindow(p2.MainWindowHandle, 0, 0, panel2.Width, panel2.Height, true);


        }
```

I have used two panels now, but I will add more after this test is over.
I don't know where the problem is.

Comment: What do you have in your `catch` block? Are you getting any error? Have your tried running as administrator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the C# application, you can load the application into the current AppDomain and treat it like a library. Add it to your project references for this. How you would initialize and put it into your panel would depend on how the referenced application is designed.

You might have to initialize the main form for that application yourself and set parent that way.

Comment: Oh really? I'll try it now! Thank you very much. Is the exe program that you want to call be okay without code?

Comment: Yes, you can do this without code if the assembly is not obfuscated. If it is, you might run into some issues.

Use http://ilspy.net/ to determine what the Main function is doing and what you need to load from their application.

Comment: OK I try it!! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
Thread.Sleep(100);
SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, this.Handle); <-- panel1.Handle
SetWindowLong(p.MainWindowHandle, GWL_STYLE, WS_VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Hi welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you add an explanation to supplement your code? Code dumps, without remarks are usually no appreciated here.